# Running WHILE or CURSOR or both in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, for-loop

I am trying to run a loop of some sort in SQL Server 2008/TSQL and I am unsure whether this should be a `WHILE` or `CURSOR` or both.  The end result is I am trying to loop through a list of user logins, then determine the unique users, then run a loop to determine how many visits it took for the user to be on the site for 5 minutes , broken out by the channel.

Table: LoginHistory

```
UserID  Channel   DateTime          DurationInSeconds
1       Website   1/1/2013 1:13PM   170
2       Mobile    1/1/2013 2:10PM   60
3       Website   1/1/2013 3:10PM   180
4       Website   1/1/2013 3:20PM   280
5       Website   1/1/2013 5:00PM   60
1       Website   1/1/2013 5:05PM   500
3       Website   1/1/2013 5:45PM   120
1       Mobile    1/1/2013 6:00PM   30
2       Mobile    1/1/2013 6:10PM   90
5       Mobile    1/1/2013 7:30PM   400
3       Website   1/1/2013 8:00PM   30
1       Mobile    1/1/2013 9:30PM   200
```

[SQL Fiddle to this schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f2ec/1)

I can `select` the unique users into a new table like so:

```
SELECT UserID
INTO #Users
FROM LoginHistory
GROUP BY UserID
```

Now, the functionality I'm trying to develop is to loop over these unique UserIDs, order the logins by DateTime, then count the number of logins needed to get to 300 seconds.

The result set I would hope to get to would look something like this:

```
UserID  TotalLogins  WebsiteLogins  MobileLogins    Loginsneededto5Min
1       4            2              2               2
2       2            2              0               0   
3       3            3              0               3
4       1            1              0               0
5       2            1              1               2
```

If I were performing this in another language, I would think it would something like this: (And apologies because this is not complete, just where I think I am going)

```
for (i in #Users):
  TotalLogins = Count(*), 
  WebsiteLogins = Count(*) WHERE Channel = 'Website', 
  MobileLogins = Count(*) WHERE Channel = 'Mobile', 
    for (i in LoginHistory):
      if Duration < 300:
        count(NumLogins) + 1
```

** Ok - I'm laughing at myself the way I combined multiple different languages/syntaxes, but this is how I am thinking about solving this **

Thoughts on a good way to accomplish this?  My preference is to use a loop so I can continue to write `if/then` logic into the code.

Comment: In spite of your preference for a loop, would a set based solution be tolerable?

Comment: @HABO I'm open to other solutions, but I know that I'll eventually want other logic, such as "which session had the longest Duration", or other calculations like that.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a recursive query will do what you want.  Also called CTEs, they are explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).  The anchor would be unique pairs of UserId/Channel and the recursion would add logins back through time until reaching the desired duration or other termination condition, e.g. a maximum lookback of 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is one of those times where a `CURSOR` would probably outperform a set based solution. Sadly, I'm not very good with cursors, so I can give you a set base solution for you to try:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY [DateTime]) RN
    FROM UserLogins
), CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  *, 1 RecursionLevel
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  B.UserID, B.Channel, B.[DateTime], 
            A.DurationInSeconds+B.DurationInSeconds, 
            B.RN, RecursionLevel+1
    FROM CTE2 A
    INNER JOIN CTE B
        ON A.UserID = B.UserID AND A.RN = B.RN - 1
)
SELECT  A.UserID,
        COUNT(*) TotalLogins,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Channel = 'Website' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WebsiteLogins,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Channel = 'Mobile' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) MobileLogins,
        ISNULL(MIN(RecursionLevel),0) LoginsNeedeto5Min
FROM UserLogins A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT UserID, MIN(RecursionLevel) RecursionLevel
            FROM CTE2 
            WHERE DurationInSeconds > 300
            GROUP BY UserID) B
    ON A.UserID = B.UserID
GROUP BY A.UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different piece-wise approach.  A minor difference is that the recursive portion terminates when it reaches 300 seconds for each user rather than summing all of the available logins.

An index on `UserId`/`StartTime` should improve performance on larger datasets.

```
declare @Logins as Table ( UserId Int, Channel VarChar(10), StartTime DateTime, DurationInSeconds Int )
insert into @Logins ( UserId, Channel, StartTime, DurationInSeconds ) values
  ( 1, 'Website', '1/1/2013 1:13PM', 170 ),
  ( 2, 'Mobile', '1/1/2013 2:10PM', 60 ),
  ( 3, 'Website', '1/1/2013 3:10PM', 180 ),
  ( 4, 'Website', '1/1/2013 3:20PM', 280 ),
  ( 5, 'Website', '1/1/2013 5:00PM', 60 ),
  ( 1, 'Website', '1/1/2013 5:05PM', 500 ),
  ( 3, 'Website', '1/1/2013 5:45PM', 120 ),
  ( 1, 'Mobile', '1/1/2013 6:00PM', 30 ),
  ( 2, 'Mobile', '1/1/2013 6:10PM', 90 ),
  ( 5, 'Mobile', '1/1/2013 7:30PM', 400 ),
  ( 3, 'Website', '1/1/2013 8:00PM', 30 ),
  ( 1, 'Mobile', '1/1/2013 9:30PM', 200 )

select * from @Logins

; with MostRecentLogins as (
  -- Logins with flags for channel and sequenced by   StartTime   (ascending) for each   UserId .
  select UserId, Channel, StartTime, DurationInSeconds,
    case when Channel = 'Website' then 1 else 0 end as WebsiteLogin,
    case when Channel = 'Mobile' then 1 else 0 end as MobileLogin,
    Row_Number() over ( partition by UserId order by StartTime ) as Seq
    from @Logins ),
  CumulativeDuration as (
  -- Start with the first login for each   UserId .
  select UserId, Seq, DurationInSeconds as CumulativeDurationInSeconds
    from MostRecentLogins
    where Seq = 1
  union all
  -- Accumulate additional logins for each   UserId   until the running total exceeds 300 or they run out of logins.
  select CD.UserId, MRL.Seq, CD.CumulativeDurationInSeconds + MRL.DurationInSeconds
    from CumulativeDuration as CD inner join
      MostRecentLogins as MRL on MRL.UserId = CD.UserId and MRL.Seq = CD.Seq + 1 and CD.CumulativeDurationInSeconds < 300 )
  -- Display the summary.
  select UserId, Sum( WebsiteLogin + MobileLogin ) as TotalLogins,
    Sum( WebsiteLogin ) as WebsiteLogins, Sum( MobileLogin ) as MobileLogins,
    ( select Max( Seq ) from CumulativeDuration where UserId = LT3.UserId and CumulativeDurationInSeconds >= 300 ) as LoginsNeededTo5Min
    from MostRecentLogins as LT3
    group by UserId
    order by UserId
```

Note that your sample results seem to have an error.  `UserId` 3 reaches 300 seconds in two calls: 180 + 120.  Your example shows three calls.